# Prevent number coercion in Postman Runner requests

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a CSV file of 20,000 entries I need to send via Postman. Some data in the CSV file includes leading/trailing zeroes on number-like data. Whenever I run this in Postman, the program automatically coerces the strings to numbers and drops the leading zeroes.

I want the Runner to send requests without removing leading/trailing zeroes from my variables.

CSV format:

```
WebId,Type,Id,[additional info]
12345,Sale,099009,...
67890,Sale,034567,...
```

The requests look like this:

> https://mydomain/api/sales/99009
> https://mydomain/api/sales/34567

These are incorrect, since the leading zero was removed.

The requests from the Runner should look like this:

> https://mydomain/api/sales/099009
> https://mydomain/api/sales/034567

I tried this in the Pre-request Script:

```
let value = pm.iterationData.get('Id')

pm.iterationData.set("Id", $string(value))
```

Runner used literal value "{{Id}}" to send requests:

> https://mydomain/api/sales/{{Id}}

How do I force Postman Runner to use the string value from my CSV? I don't want to go through 20,000 lines to add quotes to each number-like string that has a leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour, there's even an issue about it on github, with a comment explaining it: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2734#issuecomment-501155045

In case your IDs have a fixed length, the following will do what you want:

```js
var lengthOfId = 6

var id = pm.iterationData.get('Id').toString()

while (id.length < lengthOfId) id = "0" + id;

pm.variables.set("Id", id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution was to use an online tool to convert my CSV into JSON. The quotes make Postman recognize the value as a string, and it goes without saying that JSON encapsulates keys and values in quotes.